# web3.eth.getAccounts() never resolves

Tags: web3js, private-blockchain, metamask

I am attempting to connect the frontend of an application to a private chain through Metamask.
As no web3 is injected, the following code is run

```
const getWeb3 = () => ...
  ... ... ... 
  const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:30303");
  const web3 = new Web3(provider);
  resolve(web3);

initWeb3 = async () => {
  try {
     this.web3 = await getWeb3();
     this.accounts = await this.web3.eth.getAccounts();
  } catch (err) {
      alert('Failed to load web3, accounts, or contract');
      console.error(err);
  }
}
```

If I put a `console.log()` statement after the call to `web3.eth.getAccounts()` it never gets called, which to me means that the `await` statement never resolves.  What could be causing this?  The code runs when interacting with a truffle testnet; but, I cannot get it to run with the private chain..

Answer (score 1):

First, if you specify the provider in the code you do not use Metamask.

Second, the port 30303 is the default port for ethereum node in geth.
I would suggest to switch for the RPC port (by default: 8545 on geth).

I explain myself :
On geth, by default, if you want to connect a node to another you will use port 30303
-> admin.addPeer("enode://XXXXXXXXX:127.0.0.1:303030")

If you want to attach to a node without using a node yourself you can use HTTP provider :

geth attach http://127.0.0.1:8545 -> This is the HTTP provider you must use in Metamask (which uses HTTP provider)

Or, with WebSockets :
geth attach ws://127.0.0.1:8546